# C# SOAP Service - Remove method node and have header in soapheader node

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I'm tasked with creating a web service that conforms to a particular wsdl and I haven't used SOAP or asmx before.

When I create a request in SoapUI I get the following structure, which is the same as the client will be using to send requests. (using placeholder names)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://www.foo.com/schemas/method">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <par:SOAPHeaderRequest>
         <par:ApplicationID>ID</par:ApplicationID>
      </par:SOAPHeaderRequest>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <par:Body>
      </par:Body>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, when I'm trying to create the service I have this structure:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="http://www.foo.com/schemas/method">
      <request>
        <SOAPHeaderRequest>
          <ApplicationID>string</ApplicationID>
        </SOAPHeaderRequest>
        <body>
          <Property>string</Property>
        </body>
      </request>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'd like to know how to remove the Method node wrapper, and how to move the SOAPHeaderREquest into a soap:Header.

Here's my sample code:

interface and objects

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
 public interface IServiceContract
 {
     [XmlSerializerFormat]
     [OperationContract]
     ResponseObject Method(RequestObject request);
 }

 [System.Serializable()]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
 [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
 public class RequestObject
 {
     [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
     public SOAPHeaderRequest SOAPHeaderRequest;

     [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method", Order = 0)]
     public Body body;

     public RequestObject()
     {
     }

     public RequestObject(SOAPHeaderRequest SOAPHeaderRequest, Body body)
     {
         this.body = body;
     }
 }

 [System.Serializable()]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
 [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
 public class ResponseObject
 {
     [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
     public SOAPHeaderResponse SOAPHeaderResponse;

     [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method", Order = 0)]
     public Body body;
 }


 [System.Serializable()]
 public class Body
 {
     public string Property { get; set; }
 }
```

asmx

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.foo.com/schemas/method")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
public class M5NapaPartUpdateService : WebService, IServiceContract
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapMethod(SoapAction = "method")]
    public ResponseObject Method(RequestObject request)
    {
        return new ResponseObject();
    }
}
```

Let me know if there's anything else you'd need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL distinguishes between two message styles: 
document and RPC.

The message style affects the contents of the SOAP Body:
**Document style:** The SOAP Body contains one or more child elements called parts. There are no SOAP formatting rules for what the body contains; it contains whatever the sender and the receiver agrees upon.

**RPC style:**RPC implies that SOAP body contains an element with the name of the method or operation being invoked. This element in turn contains an element for each parameter of that method/operation.

Your wsdl is written in Document Literal style.

If you are using service contract then I believe you are using WCF framework to write service code.

You can specify below parameters to make WSDL as you expect.

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples"), XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, 
                             Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
```

Reference- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ws_ovw_soap_syntax_lit.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!